# AWS CLI - A file containing items to be ignored for S3 copy or sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is it somewhat possible to have a file containing ignored files and folders during uploading items through AWS CLI.

It has an `--exclude` flag like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32394703/4636715). However, the concept I seek is something like `.gitignore` or `.dockerignore` file rather than enlisting with a flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no in-built capability within the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to support `.ignore` file capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you are looking for but you could set an alias in your ~/.bash_profile something like:

```
alias s3_cp=`aws s3 cp --exclude "yadda, yadda, yadda"`
```

This would at least reduce the need to type them every time, even though it isn't in a concise file.

Edit: Here is a link that shows it doesn't look like the base config file supports what you are looking for. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html

Comment: --include or --exclude can take just one pattern at a time. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters

Comment: You can specify multiple `--exclude` statements in a command.